# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have a desktop application written for Python 3.7 and using wx lib. I use pyinstaller library to convert the application to exe desktop application using the following command:

```
pyinstaller --paths bg_services;WSserver;utils;ws_handlers;models;ui --windowed --name CaptureHub --icon=scanning.ico --clean app.py
```

This is the command log when run it

```
D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7>pyinstaller --paths bg_services;WSserver;utils;ws_handlers;models;ui --windowed --name CaptureHub --icon=scanning.ico --clean app.py
2090 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.10.1
2090 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
2091 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2093 INFO: wrote D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7\CaptureHub.spec
2100 INFO: UPX is not available.
2100 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\Users\ahmed.gamal\AppData\Local\pyinstaller
2123 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\GIT Jupiter\\Capture-Hub 3.7',
 'D:\\GIT Jupiter\\Capture-Hub 3.7\\bg_services',
 'D:\\GIT Jupiter\\Capture-Hub 3.7\\WSserver',
 'D:\\GIT Jupiter\\Capture-Hub 3.7\\utils',
 'D:\\GIT Jupiter\\Capture-Hub 3.7\\ws_handlers',
 'D:\\GIT Jupiter\\Capture-Hub 3.7\\models',
 'D:\\GIT Jupiter\\Capture-Hub 3.7\\ui']
2633 INFO: checking Analysis
2633 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
2634 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
2642 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
2706 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4842 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4960 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6041 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9057 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
9557 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
9568 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\ahmed.gamal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
9800 INFO: Analyzing D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7\app.py
10084 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10596 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10658 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10691 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11690 INFO: Processing module hooks...
11699 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11706 INFO: checking Tree
11706 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
11707 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
11967 INFO: checking Tree
11974 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
11974 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
12062 INFO: checking Tree
12062 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
12062 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
12132 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
12136 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
12139 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
12185 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
545 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): ['C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-8.0.352.8-hotspot\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\bin', 'D:\\Maven\\apache-maven-3.8.6\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\', 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd', 'C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseGit\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\', 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\', 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.3\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\ahmed.gamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin']
14003 INFO: Looking for eggs
14003 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\ahmed.gamal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
14003 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
14008 INFO: Warnings written to D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7\build\CaptureHub\warn-CaptureHub.txt
14068 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7\build\CaptureHub\xref-CaptureHub.html
14224 INFO: checking PYZ
14225 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
14225 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7\build\CaptureHub\PYZ-00.pyz
15200 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7\build\CaptureHub\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
15218 INFO: checking PKG
15218 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
15218 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) CaptureHub.pkg
15269 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) CaptureHub.pkg completed successfully.
15272 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\ahmed.gamal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit-intel\runw.exe
15272 INFO: checking EXE
15277 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
15277 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
15279 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7\build\CaptureHub\CaptureHub.exe.notanexecutable
15364 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
15392 INFO: Copying icons from ['D:\\GIT Jupiter\\Capture-Hub 3.7\\scanning.ico']
15395 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 20 bytes
15396 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 16936 bytes
15404 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
15404 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
15405 INFO: Updating manifest in D:\GIT Jupiter\Capture-Hub 3.7\build\CaptureHub\CaptureHub.exe.notanexecutable
15407 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
15417 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
15439 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
15512 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
15532 INFO: checking COLLECT
15532 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
15534 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
25103 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

and it was working fine and I didn't add new changes in the application in the last three months. I try to regenerate a new build from the application using pyinstaller, the following happens:

- in dist folder, it does not generate the same number of files and folders as it used to be.
- when run the exe file the following error happens.

  [image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx']

I tried to downgrade pyinstaller to previous version and uninstall it and install it again but it doesn't help.